# How to use function $_GET in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, get

I have below code in **phtml 1**:

```
<?php $itemid = $item->getItemId() ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('history/customer/detail', 
            ['item_id' =>$itemid]); ?>">Product Detail
</a>
```

How can I get variable **$itemid** with using function $_GET in **phtml 2.**

**Can anyone show me?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

will get you the all parameters

If you want to get specific param

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('something');
```

In your case, It should be like this

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
```

**I hope this will help**